# Scrapy not writing to csv - creates file

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

So I am trying to make my first crawler with scrapy and all has gone well so far, but for some reason I can't get my crawler to output to a csv file.

It creates the file but when I close the command prompt to stop the crawler, then open the file it created, the file is empty...

Can anyone see what I may be doing wrong and why nothing is being written to the file?

I am trying to get a list of titles and image urls from wikipedia.

```
class WikispyderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "wikiSpyder"

    custom_settings = {
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 5
    }

    allowed_domains = ['wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Unusual_articles']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(canonicalize=True, unique=True), follow=True, callback="parse_link"),
    )

    def parse_link(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = WikicrawlerItem()
        item['title'] = hxs.select('//h1[contains(@id,"firstHeading")]/text()').extract()
        item['imgURL'] = hxs.select('//div[contains(@class, "thumbinner")]//a/@href')[0].extract()
        print(item)
        yield item
```

***pipelines.py***

```
import csv

class WikicrawlerPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.csvwriter = csv.writer(open('results.csv', 'w'))

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.csvwriter.writerow([item['title'][0], item['imgURL'][0]])
        return item
```

***items.py***

```
import scrapy

class WikicrawlerItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    imgURL = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

Comment: is it printing the item?

Comment: have you registered your item pipeline correctly? does it appear in the startup logs?

Comment: yes it is printing the item and yes I placed the pipeline in settings,  I know the pipeline is working because also creates the results.csv file everytime I delete it and rerun the crawler.  The file is just blank

Comment: Are you able to write to CSV without your custom item pipeline in the settings? ie. when you do `scrapy crawl wikiSpyder -o output.csv`?

Comment: No I was not able to, but I did finally get it writing via pipeline.  Posting solution

Answer (score 0):

For some reason my program would not work if I opened my csv.writer in the init function.  After reading more documentation I tried to open the csv.writer in the open_spider function and VIOLA! I have a working writer.

***pipelines.py***

```
import csv

class WikicrawlerPipeline(object):

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.csvwriter = csv.writer(open('results.csv', 'a'))
        self.csvwriter.writerow({'Title', 'ImageURL'})
        self.ids_seen = set()
```